# Strangeness with a decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I want to make a decorator which will catch exceptions and adequately logged their.

```
def logger(foo):
    try:
        print foo()
    except Exception as e:
        print e

@logger
def d():
    return 2/2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d()
```

Thats right i think, but then I run it and I have an exception like this:

```
1

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "log.py", line 14, in <module>

    d()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Why interpreter tells me that the function has None type, but call it and print answer?

Comment: Consider reading [Wiki on decorators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators),  [PEP-0318](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) and finally [this](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your decorator needs to return a function, but it's not returning anything, hence the 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable'. You can implement it this way:

```
def logger(foo):
    def fn():
        try:
            print foo()
        except Exception as e:
            print e
    return fn
```

Check out [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators) for a good example of how to write/use a decorator.

Answer (score 2):

`logger` as you have defined, does not return a value. All such functions can be thought of as returning `None`. You have not defined your decorator correctly. It should look more like this:

```
def logger(foo):
    def _logger(foo):
        try:
            print foo()
         except Exception as e:
            print e
    return _logger
```

...but keep in mind that this loses a great deal of information, catches and swallows a great deal of exceptions, and also swallows any return values from the `foo` function so decorated. While you probably do something different in your production code than what you have shown here, the important thing is that the decorator function must itself return a function that can be called (`_logger` in my example).