# Access the Alexa Shopping and To-Do Lists with Python3 request module

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

In a nutshell, I am attempting to access my Amazon account's default Shopping List and To-Do List via Python [requests module](https://pypi.org/project/requests/). I feel like there must be a step that I am overlooking after attempting to follow the developer documentations on this topic. I went over the steps provided by the Alexa developer post *[Access the Alexa Shopping and To-Do Lists](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/access-the-alexa-shopping-and-to-do-lists.html)* and here are small commentaries from my experience from the steps provided:

1. **Configure permissions to access the Alexa lists in your skill.** 
   This step was rather simple. I started with creating my custom skill as advised [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/steps-to-build-a-custom-skill.html), but I ended up actually making the skill provided [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/steps-to-build-a-custom-skill.html#step-2-set-up-the-skill-in-the-developer-console), so essentially only completing the fist two steps. Once the custom skill was created, I was able to enable the read and write permissions for the Skill (toggled Lists Read/Write), thus giving the skill list access.
2. **Design a user intent model that uses customer Alexa lists.** 
   This step I assume is skipped?? I did not see any reference to this step anywhere on the page besides the beginning.
3. **Handling customer missing permissions.** 
   I just went to my Alexa App and enabled access inside the settings of my custom "Dev" skill in this stage.
4. **Get access the customer's Alexa lists.** 
   Here I followed the steps for [Out-of-session interaction](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/access-the-alexa-shopping-and-to-do-lists.html#out-of-session-interaction) and obtained "token". I believe this is Skill Messaging API Access Token?
5. **Implement the list management capabilities in your skill service code.** 
   This, I suppose, is where my disconnect is shown. After acquiring my token, I attempt to use the [List Management REST API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/list-skills/list-management-api-reference.html). The following Python code attempts to list out my current lists that I have with my client ID and secret values loaded from a json file in the same directory:

```
import requests
import json

def main():
    # Load client ID and Secret values
    with open("client_info.json", "r") as cred:
        clientInfo = json.load(cred)

    clientID = clientInfo["clientID"]
    clientSecret = clientInfo["clientSecret"]


    # Gettign token for api requests

    HEADERS = {
        "X-Amzn-RequestId": "d917ceac-2245-11e2-a270-0bc161cb589d",

        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    DATA = {"client_id": clientID, "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_secret": clientSecret, "scope": "alexa:skill_messaging"}

    url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token"

    DATA = json.dumps(DATA)
    response = requests.post(url, data=DATA, headers=HEADERS)
    print("Response for token: %s " % response)
    info = json.loads(response.text)
    token = info["access_token"]


    # seeing a list of all lists

    endpoint = "https://api.amazonalexa.com"
    url = endpoint + "/v2/householdlists/"

    HEADERS = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
    new_response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)

    print("Response for list info: %s " % new_response)
    print(new_response.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The print statements show the following

```
Response for token: <Response [200]> 
Response for list info: <Response [403]> 
{"Message":"Not all permissions are authorized."}
```

I am not sure if this is possible, or if there is a step that I have overlooked. Any help is much appreciated!

---

**EDIT**:

Following Christina's [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73848461/13642249), I was able to obtain the userId and create a dummy message for the skill. However, the answer was empty yet returned a 202 response code.

```
import requests
import json

def main():
    # Load client ID and Secret values
    with open("client_info.json", "r") as cred:
        clientInfo = json.load(cred)

    clientID = clientInfo["clientID"]
    clientSecret = clientInfo["clientSecret"]
    ALEXA_USER_ID = clientInfo["userID"]

    # Getting token for api requests

    HEADERS = {
        "X-Amzn-RequestId": "d917ceac-2245-11e2-a270-0bc161cb589d",

        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    DATA = {"client_id": clientID, "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_secret": clientSecret, "scope": "alexa:skill_messaging"}

    url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token"

    DATA = json.dumps(DATA)
    response = requests.post(url, data=DATA, headers=HEADERS)
    print("Response for token: %s " % response)
    info = json.loads(response.text)
    token = info["access_token"]

#######################################################################
    HEADERS = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    # v_url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/tokeninfo"
    API_URL=f"https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/skillmessages/users/{ALEXA_USER_ID}"
    a_data = {"data":{}, "expiresAfterSeconds": 60}
    a_data = json.dumps(a_data)
    a_response = requests.post(API_URL, data=a_data, headers=HEADERS)
    print("Response code: %s" % a_response)
    print(a_response.text)
    print("after response text")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Response for token: <Response [200]>
Response code: <Response [202]>

after response text
```

I believe the next step is for the Skill service to send acknowledgments to the [Skill Messaging API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html#skill-service-must-send-acknowledgments-to-the-skill-messaging-api), however I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Below is currently within my developer console along with the contents in my `lambda_function.py`:
[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This sample demonstrates handling intents from an Alexa skill using the Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Python.
# Please visit https://alexa.design/cookbook for additional examples on implementing slots, dialog management,
# session persistence, api calls, and more.
# This sample is built using the handler classes approach in skill builder.
import logging
import ask_sdk_core.utils as ask_utils

from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractRequestHandler
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractExceptionHandler
from ask_sdk_core.handler_input import HandlerInput

from ask_sdk_model import Response

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Welcome, you can say Hello or Help. Which would you like to try?"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class HelloWorldIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("HelloWorldIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Hello World!"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )


class HelpIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Help Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.HelpIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "You can say hello to me! How can I help?"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class CancelOrStopIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Single handler for Cancel and Stop Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return (ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.CancelIntent")(handler_input) or
                ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.StopIntent")(handler_input))

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Goodbye!"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .response
        )

class FallbackIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Single handler for Fallback Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.FallbackIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        logger.info("In FallbackIntentHandler")
        speech = "Hmm, I'm not sure. You can say Hello or Help. What would you like to do?"
        reprompt = "I didn't catch that. What can I help you with?"

        return handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech).ask(reprompt).response

class SessionEndedRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Session End."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("SessionEndedRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response

        # Any cleanup logic goes here.

        return handler_input.response_builder.response


class IntentReflectorHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
    It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
    for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
    handler chain below.
    """
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("IntentRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        intent_name = ask_utils.get_intent_name(handler_input)
        speak_output = "You just triggered " + intent_name + "."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )


class CatchAllExceptionHandler(AbstractExceptionHandler):
    """Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
    stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
    the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
    """
    def can_handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> bool
        return True

    def handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> Response
        logger.error(exception, exc_info=True)

        speak_output = "Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )

# The SkillBuilder object acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
# payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
# defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.


sb = SkillBuilder()

sb.add_request_handler(LaunchRequestHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(HelloWorldIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(HelpIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(CancelOrStopIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(FallbackIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(SessionEndedRequestHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(IntentReflectorHandler()) # make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers

sb.add_exception_handler(CatchAllExceptionHandler())

lambda_handler = sb.lambda_handler()
```

---

**EDIT2**:
This is the only [reference](https://alexa-skills-kit-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/ask_sdk_model.interfaces.messaging.html?highlight=message#ask_sdk_model.interfaces.messaging.message_received_request.MessageReceivedRequest) I've found for messaging.MessageReceived so far regarding python. Here is a similar SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73873445/how-to-handle-incoming-message-to-alexa-skill-from-external-app) that is trying to communicate with Alexa skill via external app

Comment: Did you have to publicly distribute your Dev skill to be able to install in on your Alexa account?

Comment: @Michael Laws I believe so yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a step between your step 4 and step 5. The token you got in step 4 is for calling [Skill Messaging API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html), which is not tied to any user. You cannot use it to call the [List Management REST API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/list-skills/list-management-api-reference.html) which is user specific.

First, you need to grab the `userId` of your account from your Skill Lambda (by invoking a `LaunchRequest` or `IntentRequest`). `userId` is persistent unless you disable/re-enable the skill.

Then, call Skill Messaging API with the token from step 4 and the `userId` to send a (dummy) message to your Skill, which allow you to pull the `consentToken`. Finally, call the list management API with the `consentToken`.

For reference, see step 2 in the [Out-of-session interaction flow](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/access-the-alexa-shopping-and-to-do-lists.html#out-of-session-interaction).

---

**Update**: For your follow-up question, the [`Messaging.MessageReceived`](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/send-a-message-request-to-a-skill.html#handle-skill-message) request is an intent request. So similar to how you handle the other intents, just create a new handler for `Messaging.MessageReceived`, e.g.

```
class MessageReceivedHandle(AbstractRequestHandler):

    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("Messaging.MessageReceived")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        logger.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        logger.info(handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.user.permissions.consent_token)
        logger.info(handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.api_access_token)
        logger.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        return None
```

And then register the new handler

```
sb.add_request_handler(MessageReceivedHandle())
```

I just log the token to CloudWatch, so after sending the dummy message via Skill Management API, you should see the token in CloudWatch and be able to use it for calling the list management API. Ideally you would store the token to something like dynamoDB (instead of CloudWatch) so your other script can read it (after sending the dummy message) and be able to query the todo lists.

Note: I'm logging both `consentToken` and `apiAccessToken` as they both are referenced in Alexa documentation. They should be the same, and you can use either one when calling the list management API.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was able to acquire the `userId` and make a dummy message to the skill. However, the response was empty, but gave a 202 response.

Comment: Let me clarify that last part. The 202 response from Skill Messaging API is expected. It just means the message has been successfully accepted. Your Skill Lambda should receive a `Messaging.MessageReceived` request with the dummy message you sent, and that's where you would grab the `consentToken`.

Comment: Found a similar question: https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/questions/246249/how-to-handle-incoming-message-to-alexa-skill-from.html

Comment: @kyrlon For the acknowledgment, you simply need to handle the incoming request in your Skill Lambda. You don't need to return a specific response structure or make a separate call to the Skill Messaging API.

Comment: If it's still not clear, can you clarify your question or the part which you got stuck?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I've been quite busy the last few days, but I'll continue to check through the documentation and provide further updates over the next week.

Comment: No problem :) You're so close being able to get it working (or at least being able to call the list management API). Good luck

Comment: I think I am not quite sure how handle the messaging.MessageReceived in my `lambda_function.py`

Comment: Nice! Now I can see my consent token, however is there no way to return this content in my response rather than it be empty? Is it necessary to use CloudWatch or DynamoDB to obtain this token?

Comment: Correct. The HTTP 202 response means Alexa accepted your request and queued it for delivery to your skill. The response doesn't mean that Alexa delivered the message, and it doesn't come from your skill, so you can't return a custom response back to the caller. Storing it to DynamoDB is probably the easiest solution. Check out [this doc](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/alexa-hosted-skills-session-persistence.html) to get started.

Comment: Thank you so much. This points me in the right direction. Your recommendation to use DynamoDB appears to be the best way to proceed.