# Alexa Out-of-Skill Authorization

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to get access to alexa list skills and according to https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/get-a-user-specific-access-token.html#endpoint-without-account-linking this should be possible by sending a request. But unfortunately this document neither states the URL the request should be sent to, nor the method (POS?).
Can someone help me out please?
I have tried various URLs I found, currently working with api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token but this just responds with a

```
<UnknownOperationException/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Creating list skills doesn't require account linking. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/steps-to-create-a-list-skill.html#alexa-lists-access
You can refer [this document](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/list-skills/list-management-api-reference.html) how to send requests to the List Management REST API. You can also send out-of-session request without Account Linking like you referred. In that case, your skill should receive Alexa.Authorization.Grant and Auth code should be in the request. Please refer the example. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/get-a-user-specific-access-token.html#example-without-account-linking

However if your skill needs to listen list events, you need to use account linking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately doesnt get me any further. Where do I send this "example with accoutn linking" to? There is no server/host specified!

Comment: If the POST request to the URL doesn't work, I'd suggest trying [Skill Messaging API](use https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html) to retrieve apiToken instead.

1. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/configure-an-application-or-service-to-send-messages-to-your-skill.html
 You should be able to get client id and client secret from bottom of permission page.
2. Send a request to Skill Messaging API using the access token you received from previous step.
3. Send a request to List Management REST with apiAccessToken.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the `Alexa.Authorization.Grant` request is part of the OAuth flow when enabling a skill that supports account linking. It is something Alexa will send to your skill lambda, as stated in the doc:

> Your skill receives authorization codes at the endpoint that you specify in the custom object of the skill manifest.

that's why there's no URI listed in the doc because you don't initiate the request.

However, it seems the doc is mixed up as there's no `Alexa.Authorization.Grant` request for skills that do not require account linking. Instead, you can follow the steps below.

###### To get user-specific access token for out-of-session calls to Alexa without account linking:

1. Store the `userId` of the desired user account. It can be found in a `LaunchRequest` or `IntentRequest`.
2. Acquire [access token](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/configure-an-application-or-service-to-send-messages-to-your-skill.html) for Skill Messaging API.
3. With the `userId` and access token, call [Skill Messaging API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html) to send a dummy message to your skill.
4. Alexa will send the dummy message to your skill as a [`Messaging.MessageReceived`](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/send-a-message-request-to-a-skill.html#handle-skill-message) request. Extract the `consentToken` from the request.
5. Call [List Management API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/list-skills/list-management-api-reference.html) with the `consentToken` to access Alexa list.

Ref: [Access the Alexa Shopping and To-Do Lists with Python3 request module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73758162/2072811)

Answer (score -1):

This is actually the information I needed: The LWA endpoint is https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token.
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/configure-an-application-or-service-to-send-messages-to-your-skill.html#lwa-endpoint